# Like operation on Json object in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, json-query

I have the JSON column in my table which is having array's of dictionary. The array has standard format.

```
[{'path': 'chat/xyz.pdf', 'file_name': 'xyz.pdf'},
 {'path': 'chat/xyl.pdf', 'file_name': 'xyl.pdf'}]
```

The table name is **chat** and column name is **attachments**. I want to perform search on file names such that even if i type one letter is typed then that row should be retrieved. For example: if i search  by string 'pd' then all values with file_name having 'pd' string should be retrieved.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it did work.

```
select distinct attachments from chat, jsonb_array_elements_text(attachments)
where value::json->>'file_name' like '%xyz%';
```

I took [reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) from documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an EXISTS condition, then you don't need the DISTINCT:

```
select c.*
from chat c
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements(c.attachments) as t(doc)
              where t.doc ->> 'file_name' like '%xyz%');
```